# How do I use impersonation in dotnet core 1.1?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

I am trying to authenticate my MSSQL connection with Trusted_Connection=True. In order to get that working, I installed NuGet package `Impersonate.AspNetCore.Windows` [(Impersonate)](https://github.com/novaworksau/Impersonate), and set it up in my Startup.cs, like so:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseWindowsImpersonation(options => {
        options.Enabled = true;
    });
}
```

In my Program.cs I added `UseIISIntegration` to setup .net core to be hosted in IIS:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

In IIS I created a new Website, changed the ApplicationPool Basic Settings to `No managed Code` and `Classic` pipeline mode. In the Advanced Settings I set the `Identity` under Process Model to an existing Windows User account:

[image: advanced application pool settings]

When I use `Trusted_Connection=True` in my connection string, the application fails to authenticate my connection to the SQL server:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DashboardDatabase": "Server=<SOME_SERVER>;Database=<SOME_DATABASE>;Trusted_Connection=True"
}
```

(where  and  are replaced by the actual names of the server and database, of course).

My question is: Am I forgetting something here?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same setup as you and I got it working. Did you add `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` to your `web.config` file? You might have to create the `web.config` file in the root folder of your application if you haven't yet. See the [package repo](https://github.com/novaworksau/Impersonate#impersonateaspnetcorewindows)

FYI I also have `Integrated Security=true;` in my connection string, not sure if that is needed.

Comment: yes, I have enabled forwardWindowsAuthToken in my web.config (which was generated by the command `dotnet publish -c Release`. I'll try the Integrated Security part, thought it was the same as `Trusted_Connection`